# Mongodb get last combination in aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

has a collection of messages:

```
{
  "date": NumberLong(1421134514),
  "sender": "53172480f9cd0e682840b9f7",
  "recipient": "52f37fbaf9cd0e02773c97b1",
  "isRead": false,
  "_id": "54b4cab2f6a48ce34f8b5a75",
  "text": "Hello!"
},
{
  "date": NumberLong(1421135561),
  "sender": "53172480f9cd0e682840b9f7",
  "recipient": "52f37fbaf9cd0e02773c97b1",
  "isRead": false,
  "_id": "54b4cec9f6a48ce34f8b6429",
  "text": "Hello 2!"
},
{
  "date": NumberLong(1421135618),
  "sender": "53072122f9cd0ee76306dc5a",
  "recipient": "52f37fbaf9cd0e02773c97b1",
  "isRead": false,
  "_id": "54b4cf02f6a48ce54f8b62f9",
  "text": "Hello 3!"
},
{
  "date": NumberLong(1421136457),
  "sender": "52f37fbaf9cd0e02773c97b1",
  "recipient": "52ea178ff9cd0e9f24d776b4",
  "isRead": false,
  "_id": "54b4d249f6a48ce54f8b6b9f"
  "text": "Hello 4!"
}
```

It is necessary to choose the latter dialogues, where the current user is either the sender or recipient.

For example, for a user with ID = '52f37fbaf9cd0e02773c97b1', should get 3 records.

It turns out to build two separate queries:

```
$result = \DB::$connection->message->aggregate(array(
    array('$match' => array('sender' => \Core::getModule('users')->user->_id)),
    array('$group' => array('_id' => '$recipient')),
));

$result2 = \DB::$connection->message->aggregate(array(
    array('$match' => array('recipient' => \Core::getModule('users')->user->_id)), 
    array('$group' => array('_id' => '$sender')),
));
```

Is it possible to somehow combine these two queries into one and sort the records by date?

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Both of your aggregate queries will only return a single element with a singular "_id" value. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Select the last posts of this person with unique interlocutors

Comment: I need to display a list of dialogues in which participated the user, and sort them by date last message.

Comment: Hmmn. So plain english where we are not trying to impress. You want unqiue conversions paired by either sender and recipient ( same values in either field ) and then select the last message between each of those pairs. Right?

Comment: Sorry for the English, I use google translate [link](https://translate.google.ru)
I think you understood me correctly.

Comment: Okay simple: `{ "sender": "52f37fbaf9cd0e02773c97b1", "recipient": "52ea178ff9cd0e9f24d776b4" } == { "sender": 52ea178ff9cd0e9f24d776b4", "recipient": ""52f37fbaf9cd0e02773c97b1" }` in your logic. Group the same, get the last.

Comment: Each record contains more field "text", I forgot to specify it here. Corrected the original collection

Comment: Please help me with the final request. Now try this

`'$match' : {
  "$or" : [
    {'sender' : '52f37fbaf9cd0e02773c97b1'},  
    {'recipient' : '52f37fbaf9cd0e02773c97b1'},
  ]
}`
How to make $group?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need here is a "unique key" value generated for each combination of "sender and recipient". If you want to do this on a regular basis then I would suggest storing the value in the document. But this is a way you can get out of the problem using the aggregation framework:

```js
 db.messages.aggregate([
    { "$project": {
       "combined": { "$map": {
           "input": { "$literal": ["A","B"] },
           "as": "bin",
           "in": { "$cond": [ 
               { "$eq": [ "$$bin", "A" ] },
               "$sender",
               "$recipient"
           ]}
       }},
       "doc": "$$ROOT"
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$combined" },
    { "$sort": { "_id": 1, "combined": 1, "doc.date": -1 } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "combined": { "$push": "$combined" },
        "doc": { "$first": "$doc" }
    }},
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$combined",
        "doc": { "$first": "$doc" }
    }}
])
```

That narrows down your sample to the "unique" 3 combinations on "sender / recipient" and returns the last document in the conversation between that "pair":

```js
{
    "_id" : [
            "52f37fbaf9cd0e02773c97b1",
            "53172480f9cd0e682840b9f7"
    ],
    "doc" : {
            "_id" : "54b4cec9f6a48ce34f8b6429",
            "date" : NumberLong(1421135561),
            "sender" : "53172480f9cd0e682840b9f7",
            "recipient" : "52f37fbaf9cd0e02773c97b1",
            "isRead" : false,
            "text" : "Hello 2!"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : [
            "52f37fbaf9cd0e02773c97b1",
            "53072122f9cd0ee76306dc5a"
    ],
    "doc" : {
            "_id" : "54b4cf02f6a48ce54f8b62f9",
            "date" : NumberLong(1421135618),
            "sender" : "53072122f9cd0ee76306dc5a",
            "recipient" : "52f37fbaf9cd0e02773c97b1",
            "isRead" : false,
            "text" : "Hello 3!"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : [
            "52ea178ff9cd0e9f24d776b4",
            "52f37fbaf9cd0e02773c97b1"
    ],
    "doc" : {
            "_id" : "54b4d249f6a48ce54f8b6b9f",
            "date" : NumberLong(1421136457),
            "sender" : "52f37fbaf9cd0e02773c97b1",
            "recipient" : "52ea178ff9cd0e9f24d776b4",
            "isRead" : false,
            "text" : "Hello 4!"
    }
}
```

Comment: _What you need here is a "unique key" value generated for each combination of "sender and recipient". If you want to do this on a regular basis then I would suggest storing the value in the document._


I thought about it, but eventually I'm afraid to stretch the limit of 16 MB per document.

Comment: @jeka5555 The 16MB limit here would really be about storing combined array combinations between `["sender","recipient"]`, in how ever many combinations and "sort ordered" combinations ( because those are unique ) of sender and possible "multiple" recipients. So many pairs in an array. That is not what I answered with really ( but also not hard to work out ). My Example shows the "aggregation grouping" you can **currently** do ( with no changes to schema or storage ) and yet get what you are asking for. I hope that the Russian translate works well enough on that content.

Comment: @jeka5555 To be clear here I'm not presenting an "or" combination  of just two `ObjectId` values for "sender/recipient". I'm presenting **all possible pairs**. But you can always narrow that down.

Comment: @jeka5555 I think this was an anwser. I certainly gave proof to that. Please do not forget to accept your answers. It helps everyone, not only the person that answered, but the community as well since there is a clear accepted response.