# How to limit/filter a query of messages to just the most recent message

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

I'm building a message inbox and it's pretty much all set! On the list of all messages, it literally has every message. I'd like this to just be a list of conversations. So instead of showing 10 messages from Person A, it only shows the most recent message from Person A. It'd also have to be an OR condition where the receiver is either person A OR person B. The same could be true of the sender. The sender is either person A OR person B.

```
<div ng-repeat="message in messages.messages" ng-class="{unread: !message.read}">
         <h5>{{message.sender}}</h5>
        <a href="#view-message" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="viewMessage(message)">{{message.message.message}}</a>
        <i>Sent {{timeAgo(message.sent)}}</i>
</div>
```

Here's the current backend to get every message instead of every conversation.

```
db.collection('messages', function (err, collection) {
    collection.find({
        receiver: req.user._id
    }).sort({
        date: -1
    }).toArray(function (err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error getting messages', err);
            throw err;
        }
        if (docs) {
            console.log('Found some messages');
            console.log(docs);
            res.send({
                messages: docs
            });
        } else {
            console.log('Didnt find messages');
            res.send({
                messages: []
            });
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: Do you want the limit and filter to be on the frontend (angular) or the backend (mongodb driver)? If backend, what version of mongodb?

Comment: It would be nice if we did it on the back end because of less load times, right? I'll check the version of mongodb. Thanks zamnuts! Edit: In package.json it says we're using Mongodb 1.4.X

Comment: MongoDB 1.4.x is the mongodb driver version, what is the version of the mongod/mongos process? 2.4, 2.6?

Comment: Not marking as a duplicate (yet). But take a look at [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27917894/mongodb-get-last-combination-in-aggregation-framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27917894/mongodb-get-last-combination-in-aggregation-framework/27919404#27919404)

Answer (score 1):

Limiting is straight-forward, use [`limit` (docs)](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/cursor.html#limit). The callback is not required since `limit` modifies the cursor returned by `find` (just like `sort`):

```
collection.find({...}).sort({...}).limit(1).toArray(...);
```

The OR logic you're seeking is provided by the [`$or` query operator (docs)](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/or/). [`$` is a special character within MongoDB](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/): it always prefixes an operator (query or update), except in the case where it is used as an [array positional operator as projection](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/). Anyways, what you're seeking is:

```
{
    $or: [
        {receiver: req.user._id},
        {sender: req.user_id}
    ]
}
```

The `$or` logical operator (as well as `$and`, and `$nor`, but not `$not`) takes an array of objects that you would normally treat as a simple query: i.e. something like `$or:[{...},{...},{...}]`.

Now to put it all together:

```
db.collection('messages', function (err, collection) {
    collection.find({
        $or: [
            {receiver: req.user._id},
            {sender: req.user_id}
        ]
    }).sort({
        date: -1
    }).limit(1).toArray(function (err, docs) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error getting messages', err);
            throw err;
        }
        if (docs) {
            console.log('Found some messages');
            console.log(docs);
            res.send({
                messages: docs
            });
        } else {
            console.log('Didnt find messages');
            res.send({
                messages: []
            });
        }
    })
});
```

Alternatively, [`find` (docs)](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#find) can accept options for sort and limit instead of using the function chaining syntax:

```
collection.find({
    $or: [
        {receiver: req.user._id},
        {sender: req.user_id}
    ]
},{
    sort:{
        date: -1
    },
    limit: 1
}).toArray(...)
```

Comment: Thank you! Such a well thought out answer! I'm trying this and it's giving me one conversation back. Is there any way to get back all conversations and limit them to the most recent message? I think perhaps an aggregate grouping of some sort? Reading the docs on aggregate as we speak...

Comment: I want to upvote this because it's such an awesome answer lol. I'm only getting one convo back though. :(

Comment: @UXGuy You want to get *all* conversations, but *limit* them? This is contradictory. You want to get *all* conversations, but sort them by most recent? What happens when there are thousands of messages... surely you'd like to impose *some* limit (maybe not 1 as I have initially thought you were requesting).

Comment: I'm thinking a conversation is a group of messages between two people. So I want just one message from every conversation.

Comment: @UXGuy My first thought then is to use the aggregation framework, I'll update the answer to reflect the new requirements. Be sure to update your question with the specific details: what type of output are you expecting (e.g. what fields, how is it organized, etc.)?